# Windows OS signature

Tags: windows, hash, cryptography, digital-signature

I am trying to add a signature some where within the OS to verify that an Windows image is correct. If you clone a computer with the image on it, it would be ok because it has all the stuff needed on there. I just don't want someone to find where the signature is located and simply copy that into their custom image and then it looks good. I was thinking of some soft of hashing technique.

Maybe get a salt value from the hardware on the computer and add a phrase to that only I would know and create a hash value out of that. Then store that in a file or registry. I would have a hash checker to verify that it's correct.

Only problem with this, is I would need to run a file to set the hash value, but not sure how to prevent people from simply taking this file and running it on their own to set the hash value.

Is there some other method to add a signature that I can verify? Or prevent people from running an application even if they have a copy of it?

Thanks

Comment: so basically you are trying to build a copy protection schema?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 in a way yes. For the program that creates the hash, a copy protection schema could work. I was also thinking that I could communicate back to the server where the application would be hosted to make sure it's running from there. It doesn't need to be 100% full proof, but enough to deter people from just taking the hasher and running it on their own box.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is this: read some hardware specific info (mac addresses ... mainboard serial ... harddisk serial ... whatever) from the box and hash that ... add some bytes to make the identifier unique and save it to the machine ... now you have some sort of identifier for that machine ... to make it a bit more tamper resilient sign that identifyer ... the program that calculates the identifyer may be found ... as long as the signing key is not present, you can't forge signed identifiers ... and since the identifier is hardware based you can recalculate it to see if the current hardware belongs to the current ID ... of course this can be tampered with, if the attacker for example starts to change the verification logic for the identifier inside your programm ...

Comment: this is what I was thinking, but the program could easily be copied from the server. What would happen is that the program would run automatically using a vbscript during the installation. The program would create a hashed signature. I'm afraid someone will come along and copy the hasher and then they can run it on any machine and when you check it with the verifier tool, then it would come up as valid when normally it would come up as invalid. Maybe I can hide a couple of reg keys or files on the system, just make it a little harder. I just want to deter people.

Comment: if i were to attack such a thing, my first thought would be to hook up a filesystem and registry monitor ... and approximately 30 seconds later your secret registry keys are no longer a secret ... you don't even need to think about it if all that should stop an attacker is some hidden info ... **won't work** ...